# Method to track visitor count on an Intranet page without using external providers

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, tracking, visitor-statistic

Since most visitor count services are based on measuring public sites I am not able to use such services.

My goal is to measure how many unique visitors are surfing on a specific Intranet site per day. The problem is that I have very litte technical possibilities since I was provided with a simple IIS web space. This means that I can only use HTML5 and JS (This site will only be accessed by iPads). Maybe there is a new HTML5 feature I am missing?

Thanks for any tips and hints.

Comment: You can use an MSSQL Database? Then you can make a very good tracking with all functionality needed/wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique visits have to be tracked on the back end. You'll need to be able to use some server side code to track people, html and JS have no idea of unique visitors they run on  the client side, so its basically static in that sense, a users computer has no idea of who else is using the site.

You'll have to use some type of backend language. (c#, PHP, VB, ...etc whole bunch of them)
You will also have to know what makes each user unique, maybe IP, but your on the intranet, that maybe the same for everyone.
You could simply have code that gets the unique id(maybe the IP), checks a text file, if its not in the text file add it to a new line, then just count the lines.

Comment: You said your running IIs, so you more then likely use C#.net or VB.net. If it was me, i would change it to an MVC application, and then have access to be bale to write a base page and functions that run everytime a page is called for from the client.